# Is it possible to suppress links to “Is it possible” questions as duplicates?

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-interface

When one asks a question starting “Is it possible”, one is usually presented with a large number of irrelevant other questions also starting “Is it possible” — this has happened as I type. If it were possible to suppress these spurious duplicates this it would much easier to check ones question for genuine duplicates — though for this question that might not work! Moreover, once the question is up, the *Related questions* list is similarly polluted, I think, though I do not see this happening now, here on meta, with this question.

The **feature I should like to see** is therefore that SE disregard such expressions (a) when selecting similar questions while the question is being asked and (b) when selected questions to display as *Related*.

What helps – if one is aware of the problem – is to ask “can one …” instead, but it would be nice if the automatic selection were aware of this and other standard unselective expressions.

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: @gnat: There is something in that (answer = yes/no, try to do it and ask about problems, SE not for feasibility studies), though I was thinking of a different case, [can one suppress macro expansion with brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819423/can-or-could-one-suppress-macro-replacement-in-c-by-enclosing-the-name-in-brac), which was about remembering/understanding the language standard(s). Better formulation might have been “shouldn’t X work like Y”.

Comment: If the phrase "Is it possible" is useless, why put it in the title of your question anyway?

Comment: downvote, vote to close as unclear.

Comment: @BSMP: The phrase is not useless but unhelpful. I put it in the title of this question as a stylistic device and to demonstrate the effect — but I don’t see it happening in the Related questions — so much the better for SE! People use it in their (non-meta) questions because it is a normal English way to ask for information and they do not know It is unhelpful on SE.

Comment: @Will: I have stated clearly what the requested feature is, though I had thought it already clear. I still maintain that it would be useful, but can imagine it may be too hard to implement efficiently – I know too little of how SE sites work to estimate that.

Comment: Nah, I meant don't bother, just vtc as unclear, downvote the question and move on.

Comment: @gnat I don't think the answer is saying that it is poorly worded, but that a bunch of unrelated questions that start with is it possible show up

Answer (score 5):

Don't rely on those suggestions to find duplicates.

- First, search for your question in SO's search field (Top right of the page)
- If that doesn't get you an answer, google the question. (Include `site:stackoverflow.com`, if desired)

If those don't return the desired result, *then* you can consider asking a question.

Generally, you'll want to consider *"Asking a question"* as a *last* option.

---

That said, there's a whole different problem with *"Is it possible..."* questions:

Those are more often than not either "tool / tutorial requests", "too broad", or "opinion based".

Comment: Both your points are fair, but some “Is it possible” questions are OK, and once one _has_ searched and concluded that one needs to ask (a) it is still possible that typing the question could throw up an answer if noise were excluded and (b) the list of related questions is also polluted by spurious duplicates.

Comment: How would SO distinguish noise from actual duplicates that happen to start with _"Is it possible"_?

Comment: SO would have to ignore this sort of standard expression that has little selective power, i.e. says nothing about the subject. In this case it is an equivalent of “can one”, which throws up fewer false positives, if any. Matches on other text should still be recognised. Perhaps some sort of weighting would be better than ignoring, but that sounds too fancy. If one does use some sort of weighting, then occurrence of significant words, especially those in tag-names, could be upweighted.

Comment: In an ideal world, I'd agree. However, the size of the process required to filter out all possible irrelevant text, multiplied by the amount of search results, would be absurd.

Comment: I don’t think that is self-evident. Perhaps one could use a list of the _n_ most useful looking words — upweighting sounds more promising than downweighting.

Comment: With that "upweighting", you'd have to have a massive list to check against. I see no practical method to make something like this happen.

Comment: SO's search engine is perhaps the second worst search engine on the web (second only because MediaWiki exists). I have been far more likely to find duplicates by starting to type a question than by using that POS.

Comment: @Cerbrus: how about a table of hashcodes for significant words, only need to do more work if a word is present. The table should be updated infrequently, of course, and could be used as a large array of bits if necessary to reduce space.

Comment: @Nicol don't get me started on MediaWiki's search. [Searching partial words, what's that](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Searching)? Yes, there [are other search engines...](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lucene-search).